# Using application Cache with on-line sites

Tags: caching, html

I tried to use the HTML5 Application Cache to improve the performances of on-line sites (all the tutorials on the web write only about usage with off-line apps)

I created the manifest listing all the js, css and images, and the performances were **really exciting**, until I found that even the page HTML was cached, despite it was not listed in the manifest.
The pages of the site are in PHP, so I don't want them to be cached.

From http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html :

> Authors are encouraged to include the main page in the manifest also, but in practice the page that referenced the manifest is automatically cached even if it isn't explicitly mentioned.

Is there a way to have this automatic caching disabled?

Note:
I know that caching can be controlled via HTTP headers, but I just wanted to try this way as it looks quite reliable, clean and powerful.

Comment: I just realized that this question should be posted on webmasters.stackexchange.com/ Will some power user move it or it is better if I open a new one?